# similar android animation for multiple views

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to achieve this effect

[image]

in Android. Esentially, when I press the main button, a "menu" of other buttons will appear. I have two Tween Animations, `inflate.xml` and `deflate.xml` that change the alpha and scale the images. I want to know if there is a way I can reuse these animations and just have each new button be animated to a different location. Is it better to use a Property Animation in this case?

As a side note, what is the best way to achieve this quarter-circle effect?

Comment: I suggest to create the animations programmatically, rather than using an xml descripted animation.

Comment: Would it be best to set the final positions of my views programmatically as well?

Comment: yes, I would always prefer a dynamic approach in case i don't know the final number of views, that'll be animated. (maybe you want to add or remove a view later)

Comment: There are some libraries available that provide a menu like this. I would check those out for sure. They've already taken care of all the animations and everything.